# How do I remove Year (annual) sub-aggregations in pivot table for monthly data while keeping year-month ordering?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a datasheet with monthly sales data. The data set contains 10 years of monthly data across 20 columns, but for the purposes of this inquire I have two columns that I care about: the date (short date) and sales (currency). The sales data I have are totals for each month, so in the date fields are always the first of each month since the day does not matter.

| Date | Monthly Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2019 | 1045.56 |
| 2/1/2019 | 500.76 |
| ... | ... |
| 5/1/2021 | 3007.87 |

When I enter the dataset into a pivot table, the pivot aggregates by Year, Quarter, and Month. What I want is a time series sorted by year-month without sub-aggregations by quarter or year. If I remove Quarter (since I don't need it), the Year aggregation will show up in the pivot. But if I remove Year as well, the pivot will attempt to aggregate across all months of the same name (e.g. combine January 2019 + January 2020 + January 2021).

Is it possible to remove the annual aggregations while keeping the months distinct by year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. Right click any of the grouping fields and select 'Ungroup', like this:

[image]

or:

2. Remove the Year, Quarter *and* Month fields, leaving the Date remaining, like this:

[image]